# How to identify DOM elements from a modal created by Angular ui-modal with Robot Framework - Selenium?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, modal-dialog, robotframework, angular-ui-modal

How to identify DOM elements from a modal created by the $ ui-modal Angular service with Robot Framework - Selenium?

I have a several modals and robot framework doesn't recognize them.

The HTML's modals is generated dynamically when an event happens on the web page.

Comment: Add context-specific example - [mcve], and a sample of what you have tried so far. With the information you've provided, hardly anyone will look into your situation.

Comment: At Stack Overflow we expect those who ask to formulate their questions with some thought. In the aforementioned guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) some of the expectations are clearly outlined. In short, the effort you put into the quality of your question will enable us to provide an answer of a similar nature.